# Applescript for ant command

Tags: applescript

Can anyone help me with an apple script to write an ant command?

Ant Command is: ant init clean compile run

Answer (score 0):

```
do shell script "ant init clean compile run"
```

[Applescript Reference: do shell script](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40)